# Python recursion with and without using global variable

Tags: python, recursion, global-variables

my code so far:

```
import statistics

def nested_median(nest, templist=[]):
    
    if not nest:
        pass
    
    elif isinstance (nest[0], list):
        nested_median(nest[0]), nested_median(nest[1:])

    elif isinstance (nest[0], int):
        templist.append(nest[0])
        nested_median(nest[1:])
        return statistics.median(templist)

    else:
        nested_median(nest[1:])
```

I am trying to write a program that takes a arbitrarily nested lists as input and returns the median of all the integers in the list and/or sublists while ignoring all other elements. So for instance:

```
nested_median([3,2,"Hello",[1,5],("Hello", "world"),5,9.3]) == 3
```

I have come up with a solution above using a global variable, but this only works for one function call since templist dosen't get cleared.I have two questions:

1. How would i go about clearing my global variable between function calls?
2. How would i implement this without using a global variable?

Comment: You aren't using a global variable.

Comment: Hint: there are two tasks to be done, so separate them: 1) read the interesting integers from a nested list, 2) calculate median of a clean list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you described as "variable not cleared", is the "Mutable Default Argument" problem. Many blogs and tutorials were writtenn about it. Here on SO see: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

---

Below is a recursive generator for flattening arbitrary nested lists slightly modified to return only integers.

```
def ifl(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):  # to flatten tuples as well: isinstance(x, (list, tuple))
        for item in x:
            yield from ifl(item)
    elif isinstance(x, int):
        yield x
    # else: ignore x

test = [3,2,"Hello",[1,5],("Hello", "world"),5,9.3]
ints = list(ifl(test))  # [3, 2, 1, 5, 5]
# ... compute median
```